# Angular 2 - Accordion toggle class must close previous accordion

Tags: javascript, angular, toggle, accordion

I'm building an accordion in Angular 2 and I what I want to accomplish is when I click on one of the accordions, the accordion will open and all other opened accordions will be closed (so basically the previously opened accordion will be closed). Without DOM manipulation.

How I'm doing this now now: I have a type boolean named 'classActive' which I toggle on true or false on click.

**(note: the accordion is being looped by using `ngFor`)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="accordion" [ngClass]="{'is-active' : classActive}">
    <div class="accordion__container">
        <div class="accordion__header" (click)="toggleClass($event)">
            <h2 class="accordion__heading">{{ name }}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion__content">
            {{ content }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'accordion',
    templateUrl: './accordion.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./accordion.component.scss']
})
export class AccordionComponent implements OnInit {
    classActive: boolean = false;

    toggleClass(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.classActive = !this.classActive;
    }
}
```

**SCSS**

```
.accordion {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, .41, 1.01);

    &.is-active {
        height: 200px;

        .accordion__content {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    &__header {
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 100px;
        padding: 0 $p-container;
        position: relative;
    }

    &__heading {
        text-transform: lowercase;
        line-height: 100px;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    &__content {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity .6s;
        padding: $p-container;
    }
}
```

I think the solution would be to set all 'classActive' on false and then set the clicked one on true. But is that possible?

Comment: But right now you have only one `classActive`, so all your accordion panels will open and close at the same time, because they're all driven by the same boolean. Use `{'is-active' : classActive==1 }` , `{'is-active' : classActive==2 }`

Comment: I have a demo to create an accordion here, please take a look this source code. btw, it will support collapse and accordion: https://github.com/tieppt/try-angular-2/blob/lesson-14/contact-app/src/app/collapse-group/collapse-group.component.ts https://github.com/tieppt/try-angular-2/blob/lesson-14/contact-app/src/app/collapse/collapse.component.ts

Comment: Do you have multiple divs (maybe using ngFor)?

Comment: @developer033 Yes, the accordion is being looped 4 times with ngFor.

Comment: @JeremyThille Hmm that actually isn't the case.. If I click one, only that one is opened. I should've mentioned the accordion is in a ngFor loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as mentioned in comments, is that you've created a single variable to handle multiple elements.

The simplest solution IMHO is to modify your `function` to "save" the current index clicked as below:

**Component:**

```
activeIndex: number = 0; // The accordion at index 0 will be open by default

toggleClass(i: number): void {
  this.activeIndex = i;
}
```

So, in your template you can just modify your `[ngClass]` to:

```
[ngClass]="{'is-active': activeIndex === i}"
```

**Template:**

```
<div *ngFor="let yourVariable of yourArray, let i = index">
  <div class="accordion" [ngClass]="{'is-active': activeIndex === i}">
    <div class="mood__container">
      <div class="mood__header" (click)="toggleClass(i)">
        <h2 class="mood__heading">{{ name }}</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion__container>
        {{ content }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check the complete code below:

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DPo5gBPWlkB4imJR1lXN?p=info)</kbd>

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction. But now I'm having two problems:
1. The previous accordion won't close.
2. Once the accordion is opened, it won't close when clicked on again.

Comment: It seems strange, because once you clicked a new *accordion*, the `activeIndex` automatically gets the *new* `index`, so in theory, your `is-active` *class* should handle the **visibility**, not?... anyway, do you have a demo(plunker) to demonstrate it?

Comment: Agreed, would think so to. I'm trying to set up a plunker right now.

Comment: As for wanting it to close when you click it again, if you simply change the contents of toggleClass to 
`if(this.activeIndex==i)
    this.activeIndex=-1;
else
    this.activeIndex=i;`
It should toggle it open or closed.

Comment: Also, I suspect the issue is from `*ngFor="let yourVariable of yourArray, let i = index"`, it should be a `;` between yourArray and let, not a `,`

Comment: @JooBeck The CSS class (is-active) should handle the visibility. And about ngFor: both ways (comma or semicolon) are correct.

Comment: The css class will make it visible, but it won't hide the visibility if he clicks it again, without some more complex CSS.  As he hasn't linked his CSS, that isn't safe to assume, especially since he mentioned it isn't toggling off.  As for the comma, good to know, I wasn't certain, I've only ever seen it with `;`

Comment: @JooBeck the point is: the accordion should only be visible when it has `is-active` class. That's why I'm saying the CSS class will handle It automatically.

Comment: Hey guys, I've made a plunker but I'm getting a error which I can't solve right now. It should give you the idea of the problem though. 
https://embed.plnkr.co/pglmScKEQFJcMFTzeHcR/

@JooBeckthanks for the solution for the close on second click!

Comment: @SennyKalidien In the plunker that you provided, you're comparing and also passing `index` not `i`. You should compare value / pass (i) variable, not index. Please check the updated answer with the demo.

Comment: The demo clears up a lot. Thanks for taking the time to help me with this! Appreciate it :)

Comment: @SennyKalidien glad to help :)

Comment: @developer033 My statement stands, in your demo once an accordion is open, clicking it a second time doesn't close it.  Senny specifically asked for that, that is what I was saying is how to fix.  The simple "is-active" i'm aware would set which one is active, and thus which to display, as I was using that in my modification, however that didn't clear which was active if clicked a second time, my modification does.

Comment: @JooBeck Well.. that's the OP: *" I want to accomplish is when I click on one of the accordions, the accordion will open and all other opened accordions will be closed (so basically the previously opened accordion will be closed)."*. I can't see where he's asking to close the same accordion if *user* performs two clicks... anyway thx for pointing that out.

Comment: @developer033 No worries, and he says it first comment on this answer, that is why I responded as a comment here.

Comment: You're right. I didn't pay attention. I notice it now: *"2. Once the accordion is opened, it won't close when clicked on again"*.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ngClass]="{'is-active' : activeIndex === i, 'is-dactive' : activeIndex != i}">

togglePopover(event, i: number) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.activeIndex = i
    console.log(this.activeIndex);
  }
```

Comment: you should add some context with your code to explain why and how it will solve the problem